# how to pass values from a jquerymobile page to a .m file

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, ios5, jquery-plugins, ios6

I have a series of form pages in my iphone app.

When the user completes the form and submits it the code needs to collate the form data and embed it into a predefined string.

Once the string has been created using the form values, i need to then pass that string so that it can be read by a .m file, for processing.

Can anyone please advise how i go about this ??

Please note I am a newbie to iphone app development

Answer (score 0):

Simply post your form using an hidden field that contains your string
or use changePage with data argument:

```
$.mobile.changePage( "../resources/results.php", {
  type: "post",
  data: $( "form#yourId" ).serialize(),
  changeHash: false
});
```